# Can someone verify my work for finding the following relations?

Tags: relations

I am working on this problem

5. Let R be the relation on the set {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} containing the ordered pairs {(1,1), (1, 2), (1,3), (2,3), (2,4), (3,1), (3,4), (3,5), (4,2), (4,5), (5,1), (5,2), (5,4)} 
   Find 
   a.$R^2$
   b.$R^5$

Here is my work so far, I chose to represent R as a zero one matrix (one means in relation, zero means not in relation) Here is R, where row number is the first in the pair while column number is the second in the pair (both one based)

$\quad$1$\quad$1$\quad$1$\quad$0$\quad$0
$\quad$0$\quad$0$\quad$1$\quad$1$\quad$0
$\quad$1$\quad$0$\quad$0$\quad$1$\quad$1
$\quad$0$\quad$1$\quad$0$\quad$0$\quad$1
$\quad$1$\quad$0$\quad$0$\quad$1$\quad$0
And based off R, here's $R^2$(boolean product of R and itself)
$\quad$1$\quad$1$\quad$1$\quad$1$\quad$1
$\quad$1$\quad$1$\quad$0$\quad$1$\quad$1
$\quad$1$\quad$1$\quad$1$\quad$1$\quad$1
$\quad$1$\quad$0$\quad$1$\quad$1$\quad$0
$\quad$1$\quad$1$\quad$1$\quad$1$\quad$1

And R$^3$ is just a matrix of all ones
So my answers are 
a.All possible combinations except (2,3), (4,2), (4,5), (5,4)
b.All possible combinations because for all n >= 3, $R^n = R^3$ 
Does everything look right? Are there any coordinates I missed in either zero one matrix?

Comment: Well, this can easily checked by a simple computer program, e.g. in R etc. It's somewhat tedious to check by hand.

Comment: @RespawnedFluff but i have the general right procedure right?

Comment: Yes, boolean maxtrix multiplication corresponds to (is in bijection with) composition of relations. In general, you [have to be careful about the order](https://books.google.com/books?id=kvoaoWOfqd8C&pg=PA499) but when it's the same matrix, it doesn't matter.

Comment: So to verify, just do normal matrix multiplication and then the non zeros correspond to being in the relation and zeros correspond to not being in the relation?